# replacing strlen by count new warning how to rewrite function correct?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have upgraded my wordpress site and get warning in the header, I am newbie in php but found answer in replacing `strlen` by `count`, then I get another warning

```
function head () {
    if (strlen ($this->description) > 0) {
    // if (count ($this->description) > 0) {
        if (function_exists ('mb_substr'))
            $description = mb_substr (strip_tags ($this->description), 0, $this->max_length);
        else
            $description = substr (strip_tags ($this->description), 0, $this->max_length);
        $description = trim (preg_replace ("/[\r\n ]+/", ' ', $description));
        $description = HeadSpace_Plugin::specialchars ($description);

        echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$description.'" />'."\r\n";
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me rewrite this function please? thank you

Comment: Post the complete warning you getting.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ??

```
  if (strlen($this->description) > 0) {
        if (function_exists ('mb_substr'))
            $description = mb_substr (strip_tags ($this->description), 0, $this->max_length);
        else
            $description = substr (strip_tags ($this->description), 0, $this->max_length);

        $description = trim (preg_replace ("/[\r\n ]+/", ' ', $description));
        $description = HeadSpace_Plugin::specialchars ($description);

      echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$description.'" />'."\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: can you post the warning you are getting?